# How to know whether a twitter account is protected or not on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I don't know how to know whether a twitter account is protected and following or  not. I was able to get it on python3. At that time, I got user object(dictionary) and then specified keys as 'protected' and 'following'.

However, on Ruby on Rails, I used .protected but it did't work.

My English is poor but please help me...!

Comment: Are you accessing Twitter through their API? Then perhaps show some code first that describes why your "I used .protected but it did't work" did not work; it will help us a lot this way. Or do you not care about their API and just wanted to know quickly if the account is protected? If so, then you could try out Ronan Lopes answer below.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a rails matter. You can do it with ruby, javascript or anything that suits better for you application. In ruby, for example, a "dumber" way to do that  would be:

```
def protected?(username)
   require 'open-uri'
   twitter_profile = open("https://www.twitter.com/#{username}").read
   if twitter_profile.include?("<span class=\"Icon Icon--protected\">")
      return true
   else
      return false
   end
end
```

It basically checks if the page contains the protected badge HTML element. Should work... hope this helps, good luck